# How to restore multiple deleted files from Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

I accidentally deleted over 1000 files.  However, Restore from Local History does not allow me to select all files.  Is there a way to restore thousands of files in Eclipse?

See these. [1](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=19389)

Alternative question: Is there a way to select files from "Restore from Local History" with the keyboard.  This would save a lot of time.

Comment: I don't suppose you had them in version control?

Comment: This has nothing to do with Java and is not programming-related. Therefore it is off-topic.